# What is the right JDBC version for MySQL server 5.1.72?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am a bit confused about what JDBC version to use for MySQL server 5.1.72.
Could you please tell me, what version I should use and why?

Comment: The latest stable one of course, unless it explicitly states that 5.1.72 is not supported.

Comment: The JDBC version you use depends on the Java version. If you are talking about the Connector/J version: the latest, of course.

Comment: You need to specify if you mean the version of the JDBC **API** (3.0, 4.0, 4.1) - which is defined by the Java version you use. Or if you mean the version of the JDBC **driver** for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The following link http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ provides a list of MySQL Connectors, choose the JDBC connector and the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Table 2.1 in [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html) could help you.

Anyway manual states:

> The current recommended version for Connector/J is 5.1. This guide covers all four connector versions, with specific notes given where a setting applies to a specific option.

Answer (score 0):

`JDBC version` does not makes sense here either you were talking about **JDBC API** then available versions are

```
JDBC 3.0
JDBC 4.0 (included in Java SE 6)
```

`JDBC 4.1, is specified by a maintenance release 1 of JSR 221
 and is included in Java SE 7`

```
The latest version, JDBC 4.2, is specified by a maintenance release 2 of JSR 221 
and is included in Java SE 8.
```

And if you are talking about **JDBC driver mysql** then it is better to use the latest version available which is 
[`Connector/J 5.1.31`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html)

It is always recommended to use the most stable version unless you find some compatibility issue.